# Trying to build a barcode scanner using CameraX and MLKit but getting "MlKitContext has not been initialized" exception at BarcodeScanning.getClient()

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm currently trying to build a barcode scanner using CameraX and MLKit but I keep getting "MlKitContext has not been initialized" exception when calling BarcodeScanning.getClient() in my BarcodeAnalyzer app. I've tried searching here on SO and on other sites, but all other examples and solutions I find either look like my code or are written in Kotlin. I can't figure out where this goes wrong! Just using the camera preview without any image analysis works just fine, but for some reason it seems like the context isn't transferred correctly to the barcode analyser or something. What am I missing?

Here's the error message:

```
E/PreviewUseCase: Binding failed in startCameraPreview: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: MlKitContext has not been initialized
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.4.0:29)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitContext.getInstance(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:2)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning.getClient(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning@@16.1.4:1)
        at com.myscannerapp.ap.barcode.BarcodeAnalyzerX.<init>(BarcodeAnalyzerX.java:29)
        at com.myscannerapp.ap.camera.ScanningCameraX$1.<init>(ScanningCameraX.java:66)
        at com.myscannerapp.ap.camera.ScanningCameraX.lambda$startCameraPreview$0(ScanningCameraX.java:66)
        at com.myscannerapp.ap.camera.-$$Lambda$ScanningCameraX$WAwB0W8s9LNCXGHteEApbFdwKUk.run(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Following is the code for my scanning fragment, scanning camera class and my barcode analyzer class. I've tried to remove code that isn't relevant to make it easier to read, hopefully that helps. Oh, and the "BarcodeCallback" class is just an interface I  use to send data to my activities.

Here's the code for my ScanningFragment:

```
public class ScanningFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicationInterface {
    private BarcodeCallback mBarcodeCallback;
    private ScanningCameraX mScanningCameraX;
    private Context mContext;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode_scanner,container,false);

        mScanningCameraX = new ScanningCameraX(mContext,view.findViewById(R.id.rt_scan_camera), mBarcodeCallback);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mBarcodeCallback = (BarcodeCallback)getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScanningCameraX.startCameraPreview();
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my ScanningCameraX class:

```
public class ScanningCameraX {
    private Context mContext;
    private PreviewView mPreviewView;
    private BarcodeCallback mBarcodeCallback;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    public ScanningCameraX (Context context, PreviewView previewView, BarcodeCallback barcodeCallback){
        mContext = context;
        mPreviewView = previewView;
        mBarcodeCallback = barcodeCallback;
    }

    public void startCameraPreview() {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(mContext);

        final Context CONTEXT = mContext;
        final PreviewView PREVIEW_VIEW = mPreviewView;
        final BarcodeCallback BARCODE_CALLBACK = mBarcodeCallback;

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                        .build();

                preview.setSurfaceProvider(PREVIEW_VIEW.getSurfaceProvider());

                ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                        new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                .build();


                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(CONTEXT), new BarcodeAnalyzerX(BARCODE_CALLBACK) {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                        int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
                        // insert future code here.
                    }
                });

                CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
                cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) CONTEXT, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("PreviewUseCase", "Binding failed in startCameraPreview: ", e);
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(mContext));
    }
}
```

And finally here's the code for my BarcodeAnalyzerX, where it all goes wrong in the "scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient();" part:

```
 public class BarcodeAnalyzerX implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private BarcodeScanner scanner;
    private BarcodeCallback mBarcodeCallback;

    public BarcodeAnalyzerX(BarcodeCallback barcodeCallback) {
        scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient();
        mBarcodeCallback = barcodeCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
        final BarcodeCallback BARCODE_CALLBACK = mBarcodeCallback;
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
            Task<List<Barcode>> result = scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
                            for (Barcode barcode:barcodes){
                                BARCODE_CALLBACK.UpdateBarcode(barcode);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                            Log.d("BarcodeAnalyzer","Analyzer failed with exception: " + e);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Barcode>> task) {
                            imageProxy.close();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there anyone who knows about this stuff and could try to help me get past this?

Comment: Hi, the MlkitContext is initialized through contentProvider which should be done automatically within app start-up time. Are you using mlkit dependencies in a dynamic feature module? It is a known issue that this is not supported currently by MLKit. Or, might it be possible that you are disabling ContentProvider somehow in your app?

Answer (score 0):

TRoque a linha
mScanningCameraX = new ScanningCameraX(mContext,view.findViewById(R.id.rt_scan_camera), mBarcodeCallback);

PARA
mScanningCameraX = new ScanningCameraX(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),view.findViewById(R.id.rt_scan_camera), mBarcodeCallback);